# I lost my Gnome-Terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gnome-terminal, delete, alacarte

**I use the app alacarte to delete my duplicate apps, but I make a mistake and I delete my gnome-terminal, I mean I can acces it, but I can't see it  in my main menu? Can someone help me with that?**

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would use here is creating a desktop entry for `gnome-terminal` again.

Create a file named Terminal.desktop on your desktop and write the following contents in it

`[Desktop Entry]
Name= Terminal
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
Icon=
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Utility;`

and save the file.

The execution path was found using the **which** command (in a terminal) like this: `which gnome-terminal` which gives the output `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`

You have to find the icon online and save it in the pictures folder put the link in front of `Icon=`

For example: 
`Icon=/home/Pictures/gnome-terminal.png`

After saving, right click the file, go to Properties, then Permissions tab and tick "Allow executing the file as a program."

Now it should be available in the main menu.

https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en

Comment: Thank's, but I still don't see the icon and from the menu, the Terminal doesn't work!

Comment: desktop file can be placed at `.local/share/applications/` so will be available from app menu for current user